# VBA - Loop for Adding records under the Same ID

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access

[image: Image of the Program Attached Here]

So Basically in this Program I need to add multiple records under the same Material Request ID (PRID). When I insert all the data and when I press submit it will ask to add another product or not .

So when I click yes to add another product the previous records should be added to the table (tblProductRequest) as well as to add the new records the combo boxes and the txt boxes should also be cleared.

I have cleared out how to do the clearing of data in the text boxes and the combo boxes but in the next time when I press submit it should save the record under the same Material Request ID and it should go on like that.

I don't know how to insert a loop to continue the procedure of keep adding items to the table under the same Material Request ID (PRID)

Product Name Combo Box = "cmbProductName"

Product ID Combo Box = "cmbProductID"

Quantity Purchased = "txtQTYPurchase"

```
Dim rsProduceMRN As New ADODB.Recordset

rsProduceMRN.Open "select * from tblProductRequest where PRID = '" & txtPRID & "' ", CurrentProject.Connection

If rsProduceMRN.EOF Then

    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "Insert into tblProductRequest(PRID, ProductID, QtyReq,DateRequested) values " _
    & " ('" & txtPRID & "', '" & cmbProductID & "'," & txtQTYPurchase & ", #" & txtDOP & "#) "

    res = MsgBox("Product Addeded to the MRN. Do you want to add a New Product?", vbYesNo, "Save Record")
    If res = vbYes Then

    cmbProductID = ""
    txtQTYPurchase = ""
    cmbProductName = ""

  Else

  DoCmd.Close
  DoCmd.OpenReport "rptMRN", acViewPreview

        End If

   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this VBA in an Access database? Is it an external connection to SQL Server or Oracle, or is it just using the local Access tables?

Comment: @Blackhawk This is using VBA in Access

Comment: AFAICS, all you want is to just `Insert Into` and remove the other code (but after validating the data of course), did I miss something?

Comment: Yes thank you very much I figured it out :) @a.s.h